# What is the Numpy version that is compatible with Python version 3.7 or above to convert a py file into an exe file using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, cx-freeze

I am compiling a py file (pm_artwork.py) into an exe file using cx_Freeze. Initially I am using:

Python 3.10.4, numpy 1.25.1, pandas 2.0.3, vs code.

During the compilation run (vs code), the program was able to produce the expected output.

However after it froze to become the exe file, I got this error when I want to run the exe file (both using cmd and manually click)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 124, in run
    module_init.run(name + "__main__")
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\console.py", line 16, in run
    exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
  File "pm_artwork.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(_dependency)
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 85, in <module>
    def empty_like(prototype, dtype=None, order=None, subok=None, shape=None):
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 221, in decorator
    return array_function_dispatch(
  File "C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 175, in decorator
    add_docstring(implementation, dispatcher.__doc__)
TypeError: add_docstring() argument 2 must be str, not None
```

I believe it has something to do with the numpy version. I've done further research, some said that they tried for numpy version lower than 1.16.

Still using Python 3.10.4, I've tried to install numpy 1.15.4, but I got this error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have already upgraded pip, but still got this error. Hence, I assume the Python version is a lot higher to be compatible with the numpy version.

Then I try to create another virtualenv with Python 3.7.9, numpy==1.15.4 can be installed inside, with pandas==1.0.1. But during py file run, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/myName/Documents/projectFolder/pm_artwork.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\myName\Documents\projectFolder\pmArtwork37\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I do read somewhere that we need to include DLL file inside the lib but I cannot comprehend what that means, can you please elaborate me on that issue also?

Here is my setup file for cx_Freeze, this is my first time using cx_Freeze hence, the includes and excludes was just trial and error. For the packages I just copy back what I imported in the py file. Please advise me on these decisions also.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from cx_Freeze import Executable, setup
import os, sys

company_name = 'ABC'
product_name = 'Report_PDF_output'
version = '0.1'

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows
base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'


executables = [Executable("pm_artwork.py",
                          base= base)
            ]
description = "Report as PDF for reference"

ROOT_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
# include_files = ['{}'.format(f) for f in os.listdir(ROOT_DIR)]
include_files = ['Fonts', 'Input (do not delete)', 'Settings (do not delete)']

print(include_files)
# excludes = []
excludes = ["tkinter", 
            "Tkinter", 
            "sqlite3", 
            "html", 
            "http" , 
            "pyodbc_data", 
            "unittest", 
            "xml"]

packages = ['getpass', 'logging', 'time', 'os', 'shutil', 'sys', 'ast', 're', 'string',
            'datetime', 'calendar', 'pandas', 'numpy', 'subprocess', 'traceback', 
            'smtplib', 'email', 'openpyxl', 'reportlab', 'arabic_reshaper', 'bidi.algorithm']
includes = ['numpy']


build_exe_options = {
    'optimize': 2,
    'packages':packages,
    'includes': includes,
    'include_files': include_files,
    "excludes": excludes,
    'include_msvcr':True,
    'silent':True,

setup(
    name = product_name,
    version = version,
    description = description, 
    executables = executables,
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options}
    
)
```

Here is my requirements.txt file content (excluding pandas and numpy version since I have mentioned above):

```
arabic-reshaper==3.0.0
cx-Freeze==6.15.5
cx-Logging==3.1.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
lief==0.13.2
numpy
openpyxl==3.1.2
pandas
Pillow==10.0.0
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
pywin32==306
reportlab==4.0.4
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2023.3
```

I need to know:

1. What is the Python version, numpy version and pandas version that can work together when frozen into an exe file?
2. What do we actually put in includes and packages, how to differentiate the needs?
3. What do we exclude usually? Especially if the program just need to do the following:

   This exe file will trigger a SAP GUI to get data from it, then it uses the data to create a pdf file as output.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

In your case, it seems that the error is related to the optimization flag, see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13248. Try to remove the optimize option from the setup call.

Regarding your general questions:

1. The following configuration works for my application under Windows:

   Python 3.10.11, numpy 1.25.2, pandas 2.1.0, cx_Freeze 6.15.7, setup.py script executed from the command line (Git Bash)

   The latest numpy 1.26.0 does not seem to work with cx_Freeze 6.15.7
2. According to the [cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup_script.html#cmdoption-arg-includes):

   > includes: comma-separated list of names of modules to include
   > packages: comma-separated list of packages to include, which includes all submodules in the package

   I usually put only modules or packages which otherwise would not be properly included by cx_Freeze and cause an error in the frozen application. The cx_Freeze code has hooks for most common packages which need any fine-tuning and these hooks are well maintained by the cx_Freeze developers, so usually I do not need to put any modules or packages explicitly for my applications, but it happens from time to time.

   As a general strategy, I start with empty includes and packages lists and add any necessary entry until the frozen application works without errors.
3. I usually exclude rather large packages of the Python standard library such as sqlite3, test, tkinter, ... as far as they are not used by the application.

   Here again, as a general strategy, I start with an empty excludes list and add entries for the largest packages while checking that the frozen application keeps working without errors.